# How to use params.fetch strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When using `rails g scaffold kittens` the strong parameters function, `kitten_params` is

```
def kitten_params
  params.fetch(:kitten, {})
end
```

I am familiar with strong parameters, 
`params.require(:kitten).permit(:name, :age)`
 but I'm not sure how to use the `fetch` method for this.

Answer (score 45):

> but I'm not sure how to use the `fetch` method for this

Simple. You do not use `fetch` for this. Since you didn't provide any properties when you created the scaffold, rails didn't know what to put into `permit` section and generated that code, most sensible for this situation. When you add some fields to your kitten form, upgrade `kitten_params` to the normal strong params "shape".

```
params.require(:kitten).permit(:name, :age)
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, now I see. Since I didn't pass any properties to the scaffolding, it used `fetch`, whereas if I DID pass properties, it would use `require` and `permit`

Comment: `params.fetch(:kitten, {})` is just an ActiveSupport way accessing a hash key and retrurning a default value if it is not set. In plain ruby it would read `params[:kitten] || {}`.

Comment: @max `params.fetch(:kitten, {})` is plain Ruby, not ActiveSupport : )

Comment: In newer versions of Rails, `params.fetch(...)` returns `ActionController::Parameters` so can you can safely chain it with `.require(...)` as needed.

Answer (score 28):

Accordingly to [Documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples), you should just add .permit at the end, like:

```
params.fetch(:kitten, {}).permit(:name, :age)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples), you can't use `.require` when you don't have an instance of an object.
Then `.fetch` supplies a default params for your uncreated object (`#new` and `#create` actions).